# The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Gilbane.SRP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a solution with two projects in it, both class libraries built with .NET Framework 4. The first is an EF model assembly called Gilbane.SRP.Data. I added that reference to the 2nd project Gilbane.SP.Logging. I keep getting the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Gilbane.SRP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

on the line in the Logger:

```
using Gilbane.SRP.Data;
```

This is even though it is required and finds it ok, Resharper shows that using as being necessary, and completion in the code editor allows me to add Gilbane.SRP.Data.

What else could it be?

Comment: Does your data project compile at the moment? I get that error periodically while in the middle of making breaking changes.  If the assembly on the lower layer cannot compile the class doesn't exist.

Comment: The lower one Gilbane.SRP.Data buids

Comment: I got it to work by setting it to .NET 3.5, then back to .NET 4 and deleting/adding .NET Framework 6 again!